# randomization of real numbers in systemverilog

Tags: random, system-verilog

I want to obtain a randomized value from the following distribution:

from 1 to 10 with probability 90%
from 100 to 1000 with probability 10%

To attain this, I wrote the following:

```
    constraint constraint_randx {
    randx dist{
        [0.001   :   0.010] :/ 90,
        [0.100   :   1.000] :/ 10
    }; }
```

After applying randomization command, I get the following error msg:

```
ncsim: *W,RNDOCS: These variables contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:
```

I saw from forum that there are some simulator which does not allow randomization of real. I am afraid, my simulator is of such a kind.

Can you please show me some solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SystemVerilog standard only defines random integral variables with integral constraints. You can scale your random variable to an int that is 1000 times your real number and scale the constraints as well. Then in post_randomize, scale the value by dividing it by 1000.0.

```
rand int randx;
real realx;
constraint constraint_randx {
    randx dist{
        [0001   :   0010] :/ 90,
        [0100   :   1000] :/ 10
    }; }
function void post_randomize();
   realx = randx/1000.0;
endfunction
```

Comment: To add to Dave's answer. Mentor seems to allow rand real (Questa 10.6/10.7) and doesn't need an additional license. Cadence will allow it if you have the license (as hevangel mentioned). But this is a valid workaround

Comment: I am pretty sure it does require a license . (I work at mentor)

Comment: You know, you may be correct. I think it requires 'svreal' (or something along those lines). I will say that Mentor requires svreal if you have any real ports in a design/test env, while Cadence doesn't seem to for just the real ports. The licensing schemes are so difficult to keep up with :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer ncsim version (I know 15+ works for sure) AND you have the mix-signal license (I forgot the exact name of that license), you can randomize real number.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem later using the following code (by introducing initialization):

```
rand real randx = 0.001;
constraint constraint_randx {
    randx dist{
        [0.001   :   0.010] :/ 90,
        [0.100   :   1.000] :/ 10
    }; }
```